# C# - LINQ to Entity query attaching the value of the properties to one variable

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have this query:

```
var sole = SoleService.All().Where(c => c.Status != 250)
               .Select(x => new { 
                    ID = x.ID, Code = new {CodeName = x.Code + x.Country}, 
                    Name = x.Name 
               })
               .Distinct()
               .OrderBy(s => s.Code);
```

Like this it gives me an error. What I want is to combine `Code` and `Country` like concat strings so I can use the new variable for my datasource. Something like - `001France`

P.S

What I am using and is working right now is this :

```
var sole = SoleService.All().Where(c => c.Status != 250)
               .Select(x => new { 
                   ID = x.ID, Code = x.Code, Name = x.Name, Country = x.Country })
               .Distinct()
               .OrderBy(s => s.Code);
```

So what I need is to modify this query so I can use `Code +Country` as one variable. Above is just my try that I thought would work.

Comment: Can you please provide the exception you are getting and a bit more context to what `SoleService.All()` returns?

Comment: Is `SoleService` an Enumerable?

Comment: give the exception message u r getting...

Comment: `DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sound like:

```
 var sole = SoleService.All().Where(c => c.Status != 250)
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x => new { 
                                ID = x.ID, 
                                Code = x.Code + x.Country, 
                                Name = x.Name
                                })
                .Distinct()
                .OrderBy(s => s.Code);
```

You don't need inner anonymous type at all. If you are working on EF, sine  string `+` is not supported, call `AsEnumerable` before doing select.

Comment: `DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.` when do it like this.

Comment: The type is `nvarchar`. I think `ToString()` is not usable in LINQ2Entities

Comment: @Leron: So you meant `Code` is `string`? Where to throw exception `DbArithmeticExpression `?

Comment: I', just guessing but maybe the `+` is not overloaded to work with strings and try to actually sum up the values.

Comment: @Leron: I have edited my answer to add `AsEnumerable`, pls check

Answer (score 2):

You can't sort by `s.Code` because it's an instance of an anonymous type. I'd go with

```
var sole = SoleService.All().Where(c => c.Status != 250)
        .Select(x => new { ID = x.ID, Code = new {CodeName = x.Code + x.Country}, Name = x.Name })
        .Distinct()
        .OrderBy(s => s.Code.CodeName);
```

Comment: `DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.` obviously `+` is not an oiton.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add .toString() because the problem should be the + operator believe you try to add numeric properties...

Like that :

```
 var sole = SoleService.All().Where(c => c.Status != 250)
        .Select(x => new { ID = x.ID, Code = new {CodeName = x.Code.ToString() + x.Country.ToString()}, Name = x.Name })
        .Distinct()
        .OrderBy(s => s.Code);
```

Comment: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.` - the error

Comment: You can try Convert.ToString(x.Code)

Comment: Nope it's the same mistake.